# Xcode 11 from App Store says app can't be installed

Tags: ios, xcode

I have faced problem when installing app to simulator. Xcode says it is successfully built. but then it shows this error:

[image]

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: mac os catalina beta 2 @excitedmicrobe

Comment: Beta 9 was released 2 days ago.  Don't you think you should upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the simulator target to an older device made that error no longer appear for me.

In my case an iPhone 5s - 10.3.1 rather than an iPhone 11 - 13.0